# Chebyshev Equioscillation Theorem in $L_{\infty}[a,b]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, measure-theory, polynomials, approximation-theory

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$.
Consider
\begin{align}
 C[a,b] 
  & :=\{f\in\mathbb{R}^{[a,b]}:f\text{ is continuous}\}\text{,} \\
 L_{\infty}[a,b]
  & :=\{f\in\mathbb{R}^{[a,b]}:f\text{ is Lebesgue-Borel measurable and essentially bounded}\}
\end{align}
equipped with the norm
\begin{equation}
 \DeclareMathOperator{\esssup}{ess sup}
 C[a,b]\ni f
  \mapsto\|f\|_{C[a,b]}:=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|
\end{equation}
and the seminorm
\begin{equation}
 L_{\infty}[a,b]\ni f
  \mapsto\|f\|_{L_{\infty}[a,b]}:=\esssup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|\text{,}
\end{equation}
respectively.
Moreover, for $n\in\mathbb{N}_0:=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, $\Pi_n[a,b]$ denotes the linear space of real algebraic polynomial functions of degree at most $n$ restricted to $[a,b]$.

The following statement is well known as *Chebyshev Equioscillation Theorem*:

> $P\in\Pi_n[a,b]$ is a *best approximation* from $\Pi_n[a,b]$ to $f\in C[a,b]$, that is,
>   \begin{equation}
>  \|P-f\|_{C[a,b]}
>   =\inf_{Q\in\Pi_n[a,b]}\|Q-f\|_{C[a,b]}
> \end{equation}
>   if and only if there exists an increasing sequence of points $x_i\in[a,b]$, $0\le i\le n+1$, and $\sigma\in\{-1,1\}$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
>  P(x_i)-f(x_i)
>   =\sigma\ (-1)^i\|P-f\|_{C[a,b]}\text{,$\quad0\le i\le n+1$.}\tag{*}
> \end{equation}

**Does a *similar* statement hold if $C[a,b]$ is replaced by $L_{\infty}[a,b]$?**

*I am particularly interested in the case $n=1$ and the implication*
\begin{equation}
 \text{$P$ is a best approximation to $f$}\implies\text{A relation similar to (*) holds.}
\end{equation}

Clearly, (*) cannot remain unchanged in the generalized setting for if $P\in\Pi_n[a,b]$ is a best approximation from $\Pi_n[a,b]$ to $f\in L_{\infty}[a,b]$ then $P$ is a best approximation from $\Pi_n[a,b]$ to each $g\in L_{\infty}[a,b]$ such that $\|g-f\|_{L_{\infty}[a,b]}=0$.

Comment: Something wrong with $(*)$. Let $\sigma =1$, then for $i=1$ lhsis greater than zero while rhs is less than zero.

Comment: @Norbert Thank you for the hint. Absolute value on the left hand side of (*) removed.